# calculating $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})(\sqrt{5} ) ] : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}]$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

calculating $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})(\sqrt{5}) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}]$ by definition this is the degree of min. polynomial of $2^{1/4}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ but I am having troubles understanding what this even means, and how I would find such a polynomial.

Comment: To start, what is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[4]{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?  How does this relate to the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$?

Comment: t^4 - 2 I assume and I'm not sure how it relates to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$

Comment: @SpamIAm would $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})(\sqrt{5}) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}) ] = 2$ if I can prove $2^{1/4} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$?

Comment: For that degree to be $2$, you’d need $\sqrt2\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt5\,)$

Comment: @Lubin why is that? and is the value $2$ correct?

Answer (score 2):

Very roughly speaking, if the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb Q$ is $f(x)$, and if $K$ is a field that has nothing to do with $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ (*), then $f$ will also be the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ over $K$.

(*) “Nothing to do with”— I don’t want to make this explicit. But the moral of my sermon is that you should expect $x^4-2$ still to be the minimal polynomial over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt5\,)$. Now prove it.

Comment: I don't really follow, all I am trying to figure out is: $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})(\sqrt{5}) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}]$

Comment: Hard to help without knowing how much of the theory you have behind you. Do you understand why knowing that $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt5, \sqrt[4]2):\Bbb Q]=8$ would show you that the degree you are interested in is $4$?